# Identical atoms in a potential energy well given heat

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity

When two neutral atoms in the potential energy well are given some amount of heat, why does the distance between them tend to increase? It seems to me from the potential energy versus distance graph that they can get to the same potential energy by both getting closer and moving further apart. I know that there is a spring analogy that says there is an imaginary spring between these atoms that is easier to expand than to compress, but how can this be inferred from the graph alone? And what is meant by ‘easier’?

Answer (score 0):

Because the graph isn't symmetric around ro and it can be shown that the average distance is increased.

[image]

Suppose this is the graph of intermolecular distance.At T=0 the atoms are in the least potential energy which in the picture is the equillibrium bond length.Let's increase the temperature a little bit:

Now the atoms have kinetic energy to be out of equillibrium and therefore the possible distances between the 2 atoms is given by the orange line:

[image]

Suppose the closest distance is rA and the furthest distance is rB

it can be shown mathematically due to assymetry of the curve around ro that:

[image]

(rA+rB)/2>=ro

Comment: This is a great start to a great answer. You might consider adding a diagram and a discussion of why pair potentials between atoms don't look exactly like the parabolic energy well of an ideal spring.